# Testing for NULL conditon using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to `Mockito` and I am trying to test a simple scenario in which `Cobertura` report says to check for null. I am traversing through the list using for each loop and I am not sure how to make `to` null.
This is the condition `if( to != null )` and I think `to` cannot be null not sure though.

Method under test

```
public boolean doHandleRequest(Object context) {
        ServiceContext ctx = AppContext.getThreadLocalServiceContext();
        cacheProvider = ( ICacheProvider ) AppContext.getBean( Constants.SPRING_BEAN_CACHE_PROVIDER );
        List<AppConfigTO> list = ( List<AppConfigTO> )getCacheProvider().getFromCache( CacheConstants.CONFIG_WSAUDITCONFIG, CacheConstants.TABLE_CACHE_KEY );

        SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext = (SOAPMessageContext)context;
        try {
            for( AppConfigTO to : list ) {
                if( to != null ) {
                    if( WS_AUDIT_HANDLER_TRACE_BOTH.equalsIgnoreCase( to.getKeyValue1() ) ) {

                        this.shouldUseMicroserviceClient( ctx.getSecurityUser() );
                        this.clientWrapper.addWsRecord( ctx, "Request: " + handleParams( ctx.getParams() ), getWsName(), toString( getDocument( soapMessageContext ) ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch( Throwable t ) {
            BaseComponent component = new BaseComponent();
            component.logException(ctx, CLASS_NAME, t);
        }

    return true;
}
```

JUnit

```
@Test
public void testDoHandleRequest() throws Exception {
    EISWSAuditHandler handler = new EISWSAuditHandler();
    handler.setWsName( "VehicleRepairsTrackingService" );

    PowerMockito.when( AppContext.getBean( Constants.SPRING_BEAN_CMS_WS_AUDIT_CLIENT_WRAPPER ) ).thenReturn( clientWrapper );
    PowerMockito.when( AppContext.getThreadLocalServiceContext() ).thenReturn( serviceContext );
    PowerMockito.when(AppContext.getBean( Constants.SPRING_BEAN_CACHE_PROVIDER ) ).thenReturn( cacheProvider );

    AppConfigTO to = new AppConfigTO();
    to.setAppCode( "EIS:DEV1" );
    to.setConfigCode( "APP_WS_AUDIT_CONFIG" );
    to.setKeyName1( "VehicleRepairsTrackingService" );
    to.setKeyValue1( "BOTH" );

    List<AppConfigTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add( to );

    when( cacheProvider.getFromCache( CacheConstants.CONFIG_WSAUDITCONFIG, CacheConstants.TABLE_CACHE_KEY ) ).thenReturn( list );

    boolean request = false;
    try {
         request = handler.doHandleRequest( messageContext );
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        assertNotNull( ex );
    }
    assertFalse( request ); 
}
```

Above test is for happy scenario and I can't make `to` null

Comment: Why can't you make it `null`?

Comment: Because id list is null the code will never go into the condition.

Comment: It doesn't mean you can't make it `null`, does it? The test might not look all that useful, but it actually is a perfectly fine test still.

Comment: Correct but cobertura doesn't cover that line. I want it green.

Comment: If the tool can't recognize that you test with `list.add(null)` and complains there is no such test case, I suggest you look into changing the tool.

Comment: hmm makes sense though. Thanks for your time Prokhorov

Comment: And unrelated: if you want be a happy unit tester: consider improving the quality of the incoming production code. In other words: read about "Clean Code" (nice book from Robert Martin) and care about things like "single layer of abstraction principle". Your method is doing quite a lot of things. And the more complex your production the harder it is to test.